# CLI or scripting language library of Adobe illustrator

Tags: javascript, command-line

I have tons of Adobe Illustrator files (ai files).
These have all same layers structure.

I want to create SVG files from each of them.
Like, a.ai => a_Layer1.svg, a_Layer2.svg, a_Layer3.svg...
b.ai => b_Layer1.svg, b_Layer2.svg, b_Layer3.svg...

Are there any good tools to do this?
It is prefer working with JavaScript(Node.js) and on WIndows,
but CLI or other scripting language and Mac OS are also acceptable.